# issue in using more than one JDBC connection in Java

Tags: java, csv, jdbc

I have an adhoc job where I have more than one jdbc connection inside for select query and then result will be exported to as csv file.

Below code runs and export csv file. When i run adhoc job once works perfectly, When I run it second time it stops in middle and it doesnot go further. Again I have to restart server once again to run job.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ADHOCJob", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void ABData(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    try {
        final String Batch_id = request.getParameter("Batch_id");
        Statement stmt = null;
            try {
                StringBuffer invitationBuffer = new StringBuffer();
                invitationBuffer.append("Batch Name")
                                .append(",")
                                .append("Campaign Id")
                                .append(",")
                                .append("Type")
                                .append(",")
                                .append("Subject Name")
                                .append(",")
                                .append("Subject Line")
                                .append(",")
                                .append("Body Template")                                                                                                        
                                .append(",")
                                .append("Sent")
                                .append(",")
                                .append("Delivered")
                                .append(",")
                                .append("Bounced")
                                .append(",")
                                .append("Opens")
                                .append(",")
                                .append("Clicks")
                                .append(",")
                                .append("Landing Page Hits")
                                .append("\n");
                BasicDataSource dataSource = (BasicDataSource) SpringApplicationContext.getBean("dataSource");
                String sql = "select b.batch_name, "+
                                   "c.campaign_id, "+ 
                                   "ab.ab_test_name, "+ 
                                   "abtxt.subject_line, "+
                                   "abtxt.body_template, "+
                                   "b.batch_meta_data_id, "+
                                   "cpi.campaign_id, "+
                                   "cpi.ab_test_id, "+
                                   "cpi.user_id, "+
                                   "cpi.invitation_id, "+
                                   "cpi.date_send, "+
                                   "cpi.comm_schedule_id, "+
                                   "cpi.comm_type_id "+
                                   "from COMM_PROCESS_INFO cpi, "+
                                       "BATCHMETADATA b, "+
                                       "CAMPAIGN c, "+
                                       "ABTEST ab, "+
                                       "ABTESTTEXT abtxt "+
                                   "where ab.ab_test_id = abtxt.ab_test_id "+
                                       "and cpi.ab_test_id = abtxt.ab_test_id "+
                                       "and cpi.batch_meta_data_id in ("+Batch_id+") "+
                                       "and b.batch_meta_data_id = cpi.batch_meta_data_id "+
                                       "and c.batch_meta_data_id = b.batch_meta_data_id "+
                                   "group by cpi.campaign_id, "+
                                     "cpi.ab_test_id, "+
                                     "cpi.batch_meta_data_id";

                stmt = dataSource.getConnection().createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
                while(rs.next()){   
                     Statement stmtABMetrics = null;
                    try{
                        String sqlABMetrics = "select abmetrics.sent, "+
                                   "abmetrics.open, "+
                                   "abmetrics.click, "+
                                   "abmetrics.signup, "+
                                   "abmetrics.bounce, "+
                                   "abmetrics.delivered,"+ 
                                   "abmetrics.unsubscribe,"+ 
                                   "abmetrics.spam, "+
                                   "abmetrics.landing_page_hits, "+
                                   "abmetrics.completions "+
                               "from ABEMAILMETRICS abmetrics "+
                               "where abmetrics.ab_test_id = "+rs.getString("ab_test_id")+ 
                                   "and abmetrics.campaign_id = "+rs.getString("campaign_id")+ 
                                   "and abmetrics.batch_meta_data_id = "+rs.getString("batch_meta_data_id");

                        stmtABMetrics= dataSource.getConnection().createStatement();
                        ResultSet rsABMetrics = stmtABMetrics.executeQuery(sqlABMetrics);
                        if (!rsABMetrics.next()) {
                        invitationBuffer.append(rs.getString("sent")).append(",");
                        }
                       }
                       catch (Exception e ) {
                       logger.debug(e,e);
                       } 
                       finally {
                            if (stmtABMetrics != null) { stmtABMetrics.close(); }
                        }
                        invitationBuffer.append(rs.getString("batch_name"))
                                        .append(",");
                        invitationBuffer.append(rs.getString("body_template"))
                                        .append(",")
                                        .append("\n");      
                }
                ByteArrayInputStream boas = new ByteArrayInputStream(invitationBuffer.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
                byte [] b = new byte[boas.available()];
                boas.read(b);
                Properties props = PropertiesUtil.getApplicationProperties();
                StringBuffer strbufMessage = new StringBuffer();
                AlertsUtil.notifyWithCSVAttachment(PropertiesUtil.getApplicationProperties().getProperty("alerts.sendUserForApplicationAlerts"), "sdsdsgamail.com", "Invitation Record ",strbufMessage ,invitationBuffer , "Sample.csv", props ,false);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                     logger.debug(e,e);
                } finally {
                    if (stmt != null) { stmt.close(); }
                }

        System.out.println("Job is running it will take few mins.You will receive an email to shortly once done "); 
} catch (Exception re) {
     logger.debug(re, re);
}
}
```

Please help me on this issue.

Comment: make your data source as singleton. Every time get the data source from there.

Comment: Why the hell are You opening several connections? as far as I can see, the connections are on the same database.

Comment: beside of all that was said about the leaking DB connections - I recommend to refactor your code into smaller functions

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. I don't see why You're creating several connections in this
   function,
2. You never close your connections.

How about something like this:

```
public void ABData(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    try {
        final String Batch_id = request.getParameter("Batch_id");
        try {
            StringBuffer invitationBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            invitationBuffer.append("Batch Name").append(",").append("Campaign Id").append(",").append("Type").append(",").append("Subject Name").append(",").append("Subject Line").append(",").append("Body Template").append(",").append("Sent").append(",").append("Delivered").append(",").append("Bounced").append(",").append("Opens").append(",").append("Clicks").append(",").append("Landing Page Hits").append("\n");
            BasicDataSource dataSource = (BasicDataSource) SpringApplicationContext.getBean("dataSource");
            try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
                    Statement stmt = connection.createStatement()) {
                String sql = "select b.batch_name,c.campaign_id, ab.ab_test_name, abtxt.subject_line, abtxt.body_template, b.batch_meta_data_id, cpi.campaign_id, cpi.ab_test_id, cpi.user_id, cpi.invitation_id, cpi.date_send, cpi.comm_schedule_id, cpi.comm_type_id from COMM_PROCESS_INFO cpi, BATCHMETADATA b, CAMPAIGN c, ABTEST ab, ABTESTTEXT abtxt where ab.ab_test_id = abtxt.ab_test_id and cpi.ab_test_id = abtxt.ab_test_id and cpi.batch_meta_data_id in (" + Batch_id + ") and b.batch_meta_data_id = cpi.batch_meta_data_id and c.batch_meta_data_id = b.batch_meta_data_id group by cpi.campaign_id,cpi.ab_test_id,cpi.batch_meta_data_id";
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
                while (rs.next()) {
                    try (Statement stmtABMetrics = connection.createStatement()) {
                        String sqlABMetrics = "select abmetrics.sent, abmetrics.open, abmetrics.click, abmetrics.signup, abmetrics.bounce, abmetrics.delivered, abmetrics.unsubscribe, abmetrics.spam, abmetrics.landing_page_hits, abmetrics.completions from ABEMAILMETRICS abmetrics where abmetrics.ab_test_id = " + rs.getString("ab_test_id") + " and abmetrics.campaign_id = " + rs.getString("campaign_id") + " and abmetrics.batch_meta_data_id = " + rs.getString("batch_meta_data_id");
                        ResultSet rsABMetrics = stmtABMetrics.executeQuery(sqlABMetrics);
                        if (!rsABMetrics.next()) {
                            invitationBuffer.append(rs.getString("sent")).append(",");
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        logger.debug(e, e);
                    }
                    invitationBuffer.append(rs.getString("batch_name")).append(",");
                    invitationBuffer.append(rs.getString("body_template")).append(",").append("\n");
                }
            }
            byte[] b = invitationBuffer.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
            Properties props = PropertiesUtil.getApplicationProperties();
            StringBuffer strbufMessage = new StringBuffer();
            AlertsUtil.notifyWithCSVAttachment(PropertiesUtil.getApplicationProperties().getProperty("alerts.sendUserForApplicationAlerts"), "sdsdsgamail.com", "Invitation Record ", strbufMessage, invitationBuffer, "Sample.csv", props, false);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.debug(e, e);
        }

        System.out.println("Job is running it will take few mins.You will receive an email to shortly once done ");
    } catch (Exception re) {
        logger.debug(re, re);
    }
}
```

Comment: Using try-with-resources (see EJP's answer), would make this a lot cleaner.

Comment: The `byte[] b = new byte[boas.available()];
            boas.read(b);` sequence is both invalid and unnecessary, and you should use a `PreparedStatement`.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel yes, I had not noticed that the statements were closed

Comment: @EJP it is unnecessary, that's for sure

Comment: So why is it there? All you need is `byte[] b = boas.toByteArray();`

Comment: @EJP in fact, you don't need boas at all: all you need is `byte[] b = invitationBuffer.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");`. I left it "as is" at first because I only dealt with connections and statements.

Answer (score 2):

You're *leaking* connections with constructions like `dataSource.getConnection().createStatement(...)`. You need to store the connection into a variable, and close it. And you don't need more that one `Connection` in this method.

Similarly you are also leaking `ResultSets`, just through failure to do anything to the contrary.

The easy way to fix all that is via try-with-resources:

```
try (Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection();
    Statement stmnt = conn.createStatement();)
{
    // ...
    try (ResultSet rs = stmnt.executeQuery(sqlABMetrics))
    {
        //  ...
    }
    // At this point the ResultSet is closed.
}
// At this point both the Statement and the Connection are closed.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a CSV library for this as you are bound to run into problems as soon as one of the values in that resultset contains a comma - you'll have to escape such values and put them within quotes. And then you also need to handle quotes inside the values. Then line endings. This can get ugly very quickly.

Try using [univocity-parsers](https://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial):

```
StringWriter output = new StringWriter();
CsvRoutines routines = new CsvRoutines();

routines.write(rsABMetrics, output);
System.out.println(output);
```

And 90% of your problems will be resolved. If you need to write custom rows to the output use `routines.setkeepResourcesOpen(true)` to keep the resultset and the writer open after the data is dumped.

Hope it helps.